# Is there a way to add a text message at the top right of the assetManager popup in grapesjs in vue component using css

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, grapesjs

Following is my assetManager popup. I want to add a text message in the highlighted red line area in the right side of the popup.

[image]

I have set the visibility to hidden for following "Add button" button and textbox. Now I want to add a text message at that place. Initially, following was the popup

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can set assetManager { custom: true } for customizing the modal and its content.
please refer https://grapesjs.com/docs/modules/Assets.html#customization